# How to use 2 functions in VBA

Tags: vba

Hope somebody can help me.

I wrote the following function which doesn't allow me to search text within text and return a result:

```
Function ErrorLabel (ErrorMessage as string) as string
    If ErrorMessage = "modified" Or "weight" then
        ErrorLabel = "Valid error"
    End If
End Function
```

Can somebody please explain how I can introduce another function find or search that allows me to search within a text?

Comment: Sorry I’m just starting to learn programming in VBA. Reading the suggested post didn’t answer my question for me. I just want to search within a cell and see whether the word exist in the cell and return a result. My question is how can I add the find function within a IF function.

Comment: `ErrorMessage = "modified" Or "weight" ` doesn't mean what you seem to think it means. You would need `ErrorMessage = "modified" Or ErrorMessage = "weight"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to see if either keyword is within the string you are passing in.

```
Function ErrorLabel (ErrorMessage as string) as string
    If cbool(instr(1, ErrorMessage, "modified", vbtextcompare)) Or _
       cbool(instr(1, ErrorMessage, "weight", vbtextcompare)) then
        ErrorLabel = "Valid error"
    else
        ErrorLabel = "Invalid error"
    End If
End Function
```